# jquery post form

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-post

I have this code for send simple data using jquery , but no works , all time reload de page and no load contents i send by post

**My code it´s this :**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form_order").submit( function () {    
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,  
            url: "indexer_adm.php?send_order2=ok",   
            success: function(data){
                $("#load_order").html(data);                          
            }   
        });   
        return false;     
    });
</script>

<form name="forma" id="form_order" method="post" action="">
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td height="30" align="center" valign="middle">
<select name="select_order">
<option value="articles">Articles</option>
<option value="blogs">Blogs</option>
<option value="products">Products</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Acceder">
<input type="hidden" name="send_order2" value="ok"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action_load" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['action_load'];?>">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<div id="load_order"></div>
```

In the div called load_order , it must load the result of this send by post from the form , but the page reload and no works , i see the code many times but i don´t understand what happen

Thank´s for All

Comment: return false is in the wrong place. indent your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, you haven't closed the submit handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_order").submit( function () {    
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,  
            url: "indexer_adm.php?send_order2=ok",   
            success: function(data){
                $("#load_order").html(data);                          
            }   
        });   
        return false;     
    }); // <---
});
```

Comment: Please you can put the right using my code for understand well , thank´s for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false inside of the `submit` block, rather than of the `ready` block.

Comment: Please you can put the right using my code for understand well , thank´s for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may have a syntax error since `return false` should stop the form from refreshing. I would use the post function instead:

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    $("#form_order").submit( function () {    
     $.post('indexer_adm.php?send_order2=ok',  $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#load_order").html(data);  
     });
     return false;   

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok !!! , Thank´s everybody

The Right code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/*
$("#load_order").show(1000);
$("#load_order").load("<?php print "".$ruta_path_adm."".$ruta_modulos."/mod_order/indexer_adm.php?send_order2=ok";?>");
*/

$("#form_order").submit( function () {    
                        $.ajax({   
                            type: "POST",
                            data : $(this).serialize(),
                            cache: false,  
                            url: "<?php print "".$ruta_path_adm."".$ruta_modulos."/mod_order/indexer_adm.php?send_order2=ok";?>",   
                            success: function(data){
                                $("#load_order").html(data); 



                            }   
                        });   

                        return false; 
                         }); 



});
</script>
```

Thank´s for the help i put bad the script and no see this , thank´s